# Class Library projects in Habitat Solution are not being published

Tags: habitat, solution-architecture

I have a solution using Habitat structure and Using Gulp for deployment. My solution contains a Web project and also class library projects. When I use Gulp scripts for deployment web project dlls are publishing to web root however class library projects dlls are not publishing into the webroot folder.

All the projects created should be a web project or Is there a way to consider class library for the publishing of class library into the webroot

Comment: You should only have Web Projects in this type of structure. However the Class Library DLLs will get pushed as well, if they are referenced from any of the Web Projects.

Comment: It is not Gulp related either. MSBuild doesn't "publish" Class Library projects.

Comment: Yeh Mark, it makes sense. Thanks!